# Sublime Text 3 - Package Control - Install | ImportError: No module named 'package_control'

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm on Windows 8 and I can't seem to install any package for Sublime Text 3. I reinstalled it, reinstalled Package Control (https://packagecontrol.io/installation) and I can find Package Control by pressing `ctrl + shift + p`.

When I try to install any package I get this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Package Control.sublime-package\package_control/package_installer.py", line 154, in on_done
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Package Control.sublime-package\package_control/package_disabler.py", line 76, in disable_packages
  ImportError: No module named 'package_control'
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: maybe this article is useful for you. https://www.rrosetta.com/computers-programming/sublime-text-3-importerror-no-module-named-package_control#comment-13388

Answer (score 36):

I had a similar issue but in *Linux Mint* environment. Here is my solution.

From the main menu open: "Preferences" > "Settings"

New Sublime instance will be separated into two frames: left for **Default** settings, and right — for **User** settings. You should edit the **right** one.

Find the section `"ignored_packages"`, probably, it looks like this:

```
{
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "0_package_control_loader",
        "Vintage"
    ]
}
```

**Now remove `0_package_control_loader`** from the list of ignored packages:

```
{
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ]
}
```

Done! Restart Sublime, and try to install package;) Hope it would help.

PS: As I see the same solution is described in one of [resolved issues](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/1091#issuecomment-190201856) by [Artem Kostrov](https://github.com/kostrovart)

Comment: This just saved me some headaches! Sublime crashed in the middle of removing a package, and afterwards everything was broken. Removing this and a few other packages from the `ignored_packages` setting has gotten things back to normal again.

Comment: my setting doesn't have 0_package_control_loader under ignored packages in user setting, but I still get the same error

Comment: @Mithril I don't remember, sorry.

Comment: Worked like a charm, even without restarting Sublime. I wonder what caused this in the first place... I never ignored anything lol.